# Writing a function with variable times in the repeat function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm hoping someone can help me write a more eloquent function to do the following:
Let's say I have a data frame looking approximately like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
d = 
  tibble(
  ID = as.factor(c("1", "2")), 
  dialect_TCU = as.numeric(c(8, 12)), 
  standard_TCU = as.numeric(c(12, 9)), 
  mixture_TCU = as.numeric(c(14, 5))
)
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to write a function that does the following:

1. Repeats each header the amount of times listed for each participant and
2. repeats the participant ID the amount of times the headers are repeated.

The ending data frame should look like this:

```
d2 = 
  tibble(
    ID = c(rep("1", 34), 
           rep("2", 26)),
    successfulRow = c(rep("dialect_TCU", 8), 
                      rep("standard_TCU", 12), 
                      rep("mixture_TCU", 14), 
                      rep("dialect_TCU", 12), 
                      rep("standard_TCU", 9), 
                      rep("mixture_TCU", 5))
  )
```

If anyone could help me out in writing a function that does this (it's probably really easy and I'm just overthinking the whole thing...), that would be extremely helpful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can reshape to 'long' with `pivot_longer` and then use `uncount` for replicating the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "successfulRow") %>%
  uncount(value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 60 × 2
   ID    successfulRow
   <fct> <chr>        
 1 1     dialect_TCU  
 2 1     dialect_TCU  
 3 1     dialect_TCU  
 4 1     dialect_TCU  
 5 1     dialect_TCU  
 6 1     dialect_TCU  
 7 1     dialect_TCU  
 8 1     dialect_TCU  
 9 1     standard_TCU 
10 1     standard_TCU 
# … with 50 more rows
```